# Uncaught throw :warden even with Devise::TestHelpers included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, warden

I am building a Rails JSON API and attempting to write tests to ensure requests without a valid auth_token are met with a 401 status.

I have included the Devise test helpers in both my spec_helper.rb (`config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller`) and in my controller spec (shown below).  I am also setting `@request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]` before each test. All of my tests where the user *is* properly authenticated are working fine, but any unauthorized requests result in:

```
 ArgumentError:
    uncaught throw :warden
```

Since Devise has removed their implementation of :token_authenticatable, I have adapted the more secure solution described [here](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6).

It may also be worth noting that I am using the [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) gem, so my ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::API rather than Base.

I have scoured the Internet and many, many Stack Overflow questions regarding this error and tried everything I could think of but no luck.  To the best of my knowledge, the Devise test helpers alone should be enough, as they are supposed to catch :warden throws and give the appropriate 401.

Any suggestions you all could provide would be greatly appreciated, and I can amend this question with more details if necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: What lines of code exactly throw the `ArgumentError`?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and found a thread on GitHub. I haven't actually had a chance to test the answer I received yet, but I figured I'd provide it for you anyways - maybe it'll work for you.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1029#issuecomment-74778193